# React-Redux -> Why is my reducer not returning the changed state to the index page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an application that has a reducer and an index page and it shall return the changed state to the index page where the action toward the reducer was called. The thing is that whenever the state changes and I log it within the reducer file I can see it being changed but I cannot see that in the index page. Why is that happening?
here is my reducer file:

```
import React from 'react'

let nextToDo = 0;

const reducer =(state = {tasks: [{}]}, action)=>
{
    console.log('thats state', state)
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'add':
            return{
                ...state,
                    name: 'new',
                    id: nextToDo+=1
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}


export default reducer
```

and here is my index.js file, where the actions are being called:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import reducer from './rootReducer'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {store} from './store'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class Index extends Component {
    render(){
        
    const {tasks} = this.props
    console.log('thats tasks', tasks)
    const add=()=>
    {
        store.dispatch(
            {
                type: 'add', 
            }
        )
    }
    store.subscribe(()=>console.log('your store is now', store.getState()))
    return (
        <div>
            {tasks.map(task=><div><p>{task.name}</p></div>)} 
            <Button onClick={()=>add()}></Button> 
        </div>
    )
}
}
const mapStateToProps=(state = {tasks: [{}]})=>
{
    return{
        tasks: state.tasks
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Index)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand what you trying to do, the probleme is here:

```
            return{
            ...state,
                name: 'new',
                id: nextToDo+=1
        }
```

You push new values to the root of the state, but then you try to get it from **state.tasks**, but your values just in the **state**

What you need is:

```
            return{
            ...state,
                tasks: [...state.tasks, { name: 'new', id: nextToDo+=1 }]
        }
```

Comment: Yes thank you very much, so correct me if I am wrong... but by doing this I am basically telling react add tasks with the said parameters to state, right? why do we have to write ...state.tasks before the parameters?

Comment: By doing this you tell redux to put new values exactly in the state.tasks
why? - because of immutability concepts in redux. In other world you could do this:
const state = {tasks: []}
state.tasks.push({...newValues});
return state;

But now have to return new state object by doing this {...state, ...state.tasks}